# Is there any way to convert webpack bundled js file into source code ts?

Tags: typescript, webpack

Is there any way to convert webpack bundled js file into source code ts?
I have bundle.js file with me bundled with webpack. Unfortunately the source code files are deleted by a stupid accident. I want to reverse engineer my bundle.js file to get back my source code typescript files. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

Do you still have your source map files by any chance (e.g.  main.bundle.js.map )?  If so, you can run your app (ng serve), open the Chrome Dev Tools in your browser and you'll see your sources in TypeScript under the tab Sources -> webpack://

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I checked and found I do have source map files but the solution doesnt seem to be working . Under webpack:// I could only see empty bundle js and commonjs files.

Comment: You should see there a folder without a name. Open it up. I've updated my answer with the image.

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache after a disk failure, thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to "download" the depacked webpack?

Comment: I had the same situation, but the code was split into endpoints (main.js, background.js, 787.9b602a0b.chunk.js, content.js), and this is a chrome extension. I used React. I have the source map. What can I do to convert it back?

Answer (score 8):

You may try using `debundle` node module.

[Debundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debundle)