# Un-webpack a javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack

We need to re-work on an old marketing landing page project, but the developer only left us a webpacked project files (build files).

Is it possible to "unwebpack" a javascript file? We need to do some modifications to the landing page javascript animations, but since the file comes from production build, it's not understandable (the functions are called e, t, c, the file has a weird name `app.js@id=fd50098646g60df97210`, etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to convert webpack bundled js file into source code ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880191/is-there-any-way-to-convert-webpack-bundled-js-file-into-source-code-ts)

Comment: Unfortunately no.. i don't have sourcemaps, only a built javascript file

Comment: It is not worth the time - believe me. You can pretty print the code and eventually find out the meaning of several variables with obfuscated (usually 1-character only) names but it will take you more headache than rebuilding the page from scratch.